# How to override Hihgchart.js Network Graph default node hover effect?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, data-visualization, breadth-first-search

I need to override the default node hover effect on a network graph in Highchart.js.
The default behaviour is that when you hover on a Node the linkedTo and linkedFrom Nodes are highlighted, the desired behaviour would be that when I hover on a Node,only the linkedFrom Nodes are highlighted, basically like a Breadth-First-Search visualization, I've managed to write the algorithm, but some extra Nodes are highlighted.

This is the algorithm I use to highlight all the Nodes, but this doesn't override the default functionality

```js
point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function () {
            var point = this,
              chart = this.series.chart,
              nodes = chart.series[0].nodes;


            bfs(this.id);

            function bfs(start) {
              const queue = [findNodeById(start)];

              // Store visited nodes in a set
              const visited = new Set();
              // Loop until we have something in the queue
              while (queue.length > 0) {

                // Pop out first element from queue
                const topNode = queue.shift();

                // Edges TO first element
                const prevEdges = topNode.linksTo;

                for (const edge of prevEdges) {
                  // For each edge find their corresponding nodes and set their state to 'hover'
                  let prevNode = findNodeById(edge.from);
                  prevNode.setState("hover");

                  // If edge is not visited yet, push to Set and add to queue
                  if (!visited.has(prevNode)) {
                    visited.add(prevNode);
                    queue.push(prevNode);
                  }
                  // nextNode.setState('inactive')
                }

 
              }
            }
           
            function findNodeById(id) {
              return nodes.filter((node) => node.id == id)[0];
            }
          },
        },
      },
```

I've tried to disable/enable the hover state, but didn't work. My approach might be completely wrong here, any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to overwrite the default `setState` function, example:

```
(function(H) {
  H.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setState = function(state) {
    var args = arguments,
      Point = H.Point,
      others = this.isNode ? this.linksTo.concat(this.linksFrom) : [this.fromNode,
        this.toNode
      ];

    if (state !== 'select') {
      others.forEach(function(linkOrNode) {
        if (linkOrNode && linkOrNode.series) {
          Point.prototype.setState.apply(linkOrNode, args);

          if (!linkOrNode.isNode) {
            if (linkOrNode.fromNode.graphic) {
              Point.prototype.setState.apply(linkOrNode.fromNode, args);
            }
                        
        /* Modification - prevent hover effect on toNode
            if (linkOrNode.toNode && linkOrNode.toNode.graphic) {
              Point.prototype.setState.apply(linkOrNode.toNode, args);
            }
        */
          }
        }
      });
    }
    Point.prototype.setState.apply(this, args);
  }
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1039zwbt/1/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! :)